# Database Engine...Sql server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have installed Sql Server 2005 Enterprise Edition... It installed just Client Services and Support Files... It did not install Database Engine... Also in SQL Server Configuration Manager->SQL Server 2005 Services and  Network Configuration is empty...

What I have to do? Is there any way to install Database Services separately...

I know that Standard and Express Editions install that Database Services also..

But I want to study how to behave when I have installed SQL Server(just server) should I install some client or what?

Can you help me? 
Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using windows XP or a home edition of Windows Vista or 7...
SQLServer Enterprise edition does not install database engine on these operations systems, because they are not server os.

You should use Standard Edition that will work for you fine, or change your os !

Comment: I am using Windows 7. 

If the OS is for example Windows Server 2003, I must choose Enterprise Edition and it will install that Engine also right?  

And on another computer,which want to connect that database, should be installed what? Just SQL Server Management Studio yes? 

Did I understand right?

Comment: answer to all of your questions are yes